# passing array with fixed-length strings to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, size

I'm trying to make the program launch a separate process that simply lists files in long format in linux. (in other words, I'm trying to make my program execute "ls -al"). The  problem I have is that the compiler keeps warning me with this message: `warning: passing argument 2 of 'run' from incompatible pointer type`

How do I fix this?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

    void run(char *app,char* param[250]){
        if (fork()==0){
        execvp(app,param);
        }else{
        wait(NULL);
        }
    }

int main(){
      printf("Running ls -al...\n");
      char param[10][250];
      strcpy(param[0],"ls");
      strcpy(param[1],"-al");
      param[2][0]='\0';
      run("/usr/bin/ls",param);
      printf("\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: this expression: `param[2][0]='\0';`  is not correct.  the last entry in an argument list is `char *` to NULL,  not a single 0x00 byte but a 'pointer sized (4 bytes on a 32 bit architecture) array of all 0x00 I.E. the last entry in the list of argument pointers needs to be '0x00000000' (for a 32 bit architecture) I.E. a pointer to address 0

Comment: please read the man page for `fork()`.   fork() can return 3 different things.  1) =0 then child process running.  2) >0 then parent process running(and child successfully started)  3) <0 then child process not started and the `errno` system variable indicates the reason for the failure to start the child process.   The posted code makes the (not necessarily valid) assumption that the start of the child process was successful.

Comment: the call to `execvp()`  can fail.  if it fails, then control is returned to the next statement following the call to `execvp()`  which should be a call to `perror()` followed by a call to `exit()`

Comment: overall, if either fork() fails or execvp() fails then the code will execute `wait()`, perhaps forever waiting for a child event, that will never occur.  In other words, always check the returned values from calls to system functions to assure they were successful

Comment: I have read the manual for fork. as I'm working on the code, I can sometimes get the program to run but the parameters aren't being passed in. I know the problem is with my string array (multi-index char array) but I don't know how to make the function receive the data in the format that execvp expects

Comment: the problem is NOT in the 'multi-index char array', but rather in the setting up of the param variable and the setting up of the subsequent parameters.  See my answer for further details and how to correctly setup the parameter list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amongst other things wrong with the code:

this expression: `char* param[250]` (second parameter of the `run()` function)

says that the parameter is a pointer to an array of 250 pointers to character arrays.

That is not correct.

The expression should be: `char * param[]`

it would have been better, back in main() to define param as:

```
char ** param = NULL;
```

then allocate an appropriate amount of memory while checking for errors

```
if( NULL == (param = malloc( 3* sizeof (char*) ) )
{ // then malloc failed
    perror( "malloc for array of parameters failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful
```

then for the parameter values and parameter list terminator:

```
 param[0] = "ls";  // sets a pointer
 param[1] = "-al"; // sets a pointer
 param[2] = NULL;
```